# Read fasta sequence

Tags: python, sequence, biopython, fasta, dna-sequence

I have been trying to read the fasta sequence, but somehow, it is always skipping the last sequence.

Could you please help me, what am I missing here. Here is the code below.

```
import sys
fasta = []
test = []
with open("tests.fasta") as file_one:
    for line in file_one:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
           continue
        if line.startswith(">"):
            active_sequence_name = line[1:]
            if active_sequence_name not in fasta:
                test.append(''.join(fasta))
                fasta = []
            continue
        sequence = line
        fasta.append(sequence)
print(test)
```

and below is the fasta sequence

```
>1FN3:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
VLSPADKTNVKAAWGKVGAHAGEYGAEALERMFLSFPTTKTYFPHFDLSHGSAQVKGHGKKVADALTNAVAHVDDMPNAL
SALSDLHAHKLRVDPVNFKLLSHCLLVTLAAHLPAEFTPAVHASLDKFLASVSTVLTSKYR

>5OKT:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
MGSSHHHHHHSSGLVPRGSHMELRVGNRYRLGRKIGSGSFGDIYLGTDIAAGEEVAIKLECVKTKHPQLHIESKIYKMMQ
GGVGIPTIRWCGAEGDYNVMVMELLGPSLEDLFNFCSRKFSLKTVLLLADQMISRIEYIHSKNFIHRDVKPDNFLMGLGK
KGNLVYIIDFGLAKKYRDARTHQHIPYRENKNLTGTARYASINTHLGIEQSRRDDLESLGYVLMYFNLGSLPWQGLKAAT
KRQKYERISEKKMSTPIEVLCKGYPSEFATYLNFCRSLRFDDKPDYSYLRQLFRNLFHRQGFSYDYVFDWNMLK*

>2PAB:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
GPTGTGESKCPLMVKVLDAVRGSPAINVAVHVFRKAADDTWEPFASGKTSESGELHGLTTEEQFVEGIYKVEIDTKSYWK
ALGISPFHEHAEVVFTANDSGPRRYTIAALLSPYSYSTTAVVTNPKE*

>3IDP:B|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
HHHHHHDRNRMKTLGRRDSSDDWEIPDGQITVGQRIGSGSFGTVYKGKWHGDVAVKMLNVTAPTPQQLQAFKNEVGVLRK
TRHVNILLFMGYSTKPQLAIVTQWCEGSSLYHHLHIIETKFEMIKLIDIARQTAQGMDYLHAKSIIHRDLKSNNIFLHED
LTVKIGDFGLATEKSRWSGSHQFEQLSGSILWMAPEVIRMQDKNPYSFQSDVYAFGIVLYELMTGQLPYSNINNRDQIIF
MVGRGYLSPDLSKVRSNCPKAMKRLMAECLKKKRDERPLFPQILASIELLARSLPKIHRS

>4QUD:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
MENTENSVDSKSIKNLEPKIIHGSESMDSGISLDNSYKMDYPEMGLCIIINNKNFHKSTGMTSRSGTDVDAANLRETFRN
LKYEVRNKNDLTREEIVELMRDVSKEDHSKRSSFVCVLLSHGEEGIIFGTNGPVDLKKIFNFFRGDRCRSLTGKPKLFII
QACRGTELDCGIETDSGVDDDMACHKIPVEADFLYAYSTAPGYYSWRNSKDGSWFIQSLCAMLKQYADKLEFMHILTRVN
RKVATEFESFSFDATFHAKKQIPCIVSMLTKELYFYH
```

Comment: Somehow it is taking as blockquote because of that symobol '>'
Yes data end with newline. Every single line is newline

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you so much for editing the dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a FASTA block only gets appended to `test` when a new starting line is read, but there is no starting line at the end of the file, so the last block doesn't get appended. So you need to deal with that at the end of the loop. Like this:

```
import sys

fasta = []
test = []
with open("tests.fasta") as file_one:
    for line in file_one:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
           continue
        if line.startswith(">"):
            active_sequence_name = line[1:]
            if active_sequence_name not in fasta:
                test.append(''.join(fasta))
                fasta = []
            continue
        sequence = line
        fasta.append(sequence)

# Flush the last fasta block to the test list
if fasta:
    test.append(''.join(fasta))

# Print the test list
for i, row in enumerate(test):
    print(i)
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
0

1
VLSPADKTNVKAAWGKVGAHAGEYGAEALERMFLSFPTTKTYFPHFDLSHGSAQVKGHGKKVADALTNAVAHVDDMPNALSALSDLHAHKLRVDPVNFKLLSHCLLVTLAAHLPAEFTPAVHASLDKFLASVSTVLTSKYR
2
MGSSHHHHHHSSGLVPRGSHMELRVGNRYRLGRKIGSGSFGDIYLGTDIAAGEEVAIKLECVKTKHPQLHIESKIYKMMQGGVGIPTIRWCGAEGDYNVMVMELLGPSLEDLFNFCSRKFSLKTVLLLADQMISRIEYIHSKNFIHRDVKPDNFLMGLGKKGNLVYIIDFGLAKKYRDARTHQHIPYRENKNLTGTARYASINTHLGIEQSRRDDLESLGYVLMYFNLGSLPWQGLKAATKRQKYERISEKKMSTPIEVLCKGYPSEFATYLNFCRSLRFDDKPDYSYLRQLFRNLFHRQGFSYDYVFDWNMLK*
3
GPTGTGESKCPLMVKVLDAVRGSPAINVAVHVFRKAADDTWEPFASGKTSESGELHGLTTEEQFVEGIYKVEIDTKSYWKALGISPFHEHAEVVFTANDSGPRRYTIAALLSPYSYSTTAVVTNPKE*
4
HHHHHHDRNRMKTLGRRDSSDDWEIPDGQITVGQRIGSGSFGTVYKGKWHGDVAVKMLNVTAPTPQQLQAFKNEVGVLRKTRHVNILLFMGYSTKPQLAIVTQWCEGSSLYHHLHIIETKFEMIKLIDIARQTAQGMDYLHAKSIIHRDLKSNNIFLHEDLTVKIGDFGLATEKSRWSGSHQFEQLSGSILWMAPEVIRMQDKNPYSFQSDVYAFGIVLYELMTGQLPYSNINNRDQIIFMVGRGYLSPDLSKVRSNCPKAMKRLMAECLKKKRDERPLFPQILASIELLARSLPKIHRS
5
MENTENSVDSKSIKNLEPKIIHGSESMDSGISLDNSYKMDYPEMGLCIIINNKNFHKSTGMTSRSGTDVDAANLRETFRNLKYEVRNKNDLTREEIVELMRDVSKEDHSKRSSFVCVLLSHGEEGIIFGTNGPVDLKKIFNFFRGDRCRSLTGKPKLFIIQACRGTELDCGIETDSGVDDDMACHKIPVEADFLYAYSTAPGYYSWRNSKDGSWFIQSLCAMLKQYADKLEFMHILTRVNRKVATEFESFSFDATFHAKKQIPCIVSMLTKELYFYH
```

Comment: Awesome. Any idea, how to omit the 0th row. Because technically, we have only 5 sequence, so it also must have 5 items in the list.

Comment: I got it, never mind. Thank you so much for the help